# not getting @PostConstructor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

## here I am unable to find @PostContructor[image]

need @PostConstructor

Comment: What is `@PostConstructor` in this context? Did you mean `@PostConstruct` perhaps?

Comment: yes @PostConstruct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are referring to `@PostConstruct` here.

Note that both the @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy annotations are part of Java EE. Since Java EE was deprecated in Java 9, and removed in Java 11, we have to add an additional dependency to use these annotations:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```